# Java: Access Object of a class created inside switch

Tags: java, class, object, switch-statement, case

I have scenario like below :

```
String artifactName="testplan"; //or at times "testsuite" can come
switch (artifactName) {
            case testplan: {
                TestPlan artifact = new TestPlan();
            }
            case testsuite: {
                TestSuite artifact = new TestSuite();   
            }
```

From the above I wish to get the artifact object outside the switch.
In both the classes(TestSuite and TestPlan) I have a attribute, which I would be  setting as I get the artifact and use object accordingly. To be precise,I will be using this to convert this object to xml(xml varies according to class). How do  I do get the artofact out of switch ? How do I get the object when the class varies inside switch case.
Please help me the earliest.

Comment: You could just declare `artifact` outside of the switch as `Object artifact`

Comment: Yeah. Got it!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can do the folowing as well:

```
    String artifactName="testplan"; 
    Object artifact;//create reference 


    switch (artifactName) {
                case testplan: {
                    artifact = new TestPlan();//assing it here
                    break;
                }
                case testsuite: {
                    artifact = new TestSuite();//or here 
                    break;
                }
```

So you need to work directly on the instance of one of your classes. You know. I`m new to Java at all. And if someone will provide better idea for doing that it will be good. But for now I see the one solution.

```
  if(object instanceof TestPlan){
        ((TestPlan) object).doMethod();
    }else if (object instanceof TestSuite){
        ((TestSuite)object).doMethod();
    }
```

But be aware that if no switch cases were met it will be still null.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But after the switch execution, I will have  artifact.setCustomAttribute("sdfsdf"). This setCustomAttribute method is there for both testplan and testsuite class/object. When Im trying the above suggested way,Im getting message like "The method setCustomAttribute(RQMCustomAttributes) is undefined for the type Object". Kindly help me.

Comment: I have Edited my answer for you

Answer (score 2):

Create reference 'artifact' of type **TestPlan** (**TestSuite** extends **TestPlan**) outside the switch block and then inside the case statements assign the object(TestPlan/TestSuite) according to your required Condition. Below code works fine.

If You want to use a common method which is available in both the classes and use the concept of inheritance and Polymorphism. You can extends TestPlan(Parent) in TestSuite(child) and Instead of Object Reference You can Use TestPlan reference.

```
 String artifactName="testplan"; 
        TestPlan artifact;// Test Plan is the Parent class and extend it to TestSuite
        switch (artifactName) {
                    case "testvplan": {
                        artifact = new TestPlan();
                        break;
                    }
                    case "testsuite": {
                        artifact = new TestSuite();   
                        break;
                    }
                    default : {
                        //some code for default condition
                    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But after the switch execution, I will have  artifact.setCustomAttribute("sdfsdf"). This setCustomAttribute method is there for both testplan and testsuite class/object. When I'm trying the above suggested way,Im getting message like "The method setCustomAttribute(RQMCustomAttributes) is undefined for the type Object". Kindly help me.

Comment: This is because setCustomAttribute(String) is not defined in object class and you are calling the method on Object class reference .